# How check error codes with couchbase gocb?

Tags: go, couchbase

When handling errors returned by [gocb](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/gocb) (the official Couchbase Go Client) I would like to check for specific status codes (e.g. `StatusKeyNotFound` or `StatusKeyExists`).

Like so

```
_, err := bucket.Get(key, entity)
if err != nil {
    if err == gocb.ErrKeyNotFound {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this be done?

In `gocbcore`, error.go we have the [following definition](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/gocb/blob/master/gocbcore/error.go#L36):

```
type memdError struct {
    code StatusCode
}

// ...

func (e memdError) KeyNotFound() bool {
    return e.code == StatusKeyNotFound
}
func (e memdError) KeyExists() bool {
    return e.code == StatusKeyExists
}
func (e memdError) Temporary() bool {
    return e.code == StatusOutOfMemory || e.code == StatusTmpFail
}
func (e memdError) AuthError() bool {
    return e.code == StatusAuthError
}
func (e memdError) ValueTooBig() bool {
    return e.code == StatusTooBig
}
func (e memdError) NotStored() bool {
    return e.code == StatusNotStored
}
func (e memdError) BadDelta() bool {
    return e.code == StatusBadDelta
}
```

Note that `memdError` is unexported, so you can't use it in a type assertion.

So, take a different approach: define your own interface:

```
type MyErrorInterface interface {
    KeyNotFound() bool
    KeyExists() bool
}
```

And assert whatever error you get back from `gocb` to your interface:

```
_, err := bucket.Get(key, entity)

if err != nil {
    if se, ok = err.(MyErrorInterface); ok {
        if se.KeyNotFound() {
            // handle KeyNotFound
        }
        if se.KeyExists() {
            // handle KeyExists
        }
    } else {
        // no information about states
    }
}
```